# Why doesn't $v_T = \omega r$ involve the direction of its variables?

Tags: vectors, velocity, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

We derived $v_T = \omega r$ by the following procedure, and it's said that $v_T = \omega r$ "is a relation between the **magnitudes** of the tangential linear velocity and the angular velocity". Why doesn't the formula involve the direction of its variables?

---

We first define
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The direction is implied to be in the $\hat{\phi}$ direction because it is assumed that (eq 8-9) $r$ is not changing with time. Moreover, it's not *really* implied since it's the tangential velocity and so is in the tangential ($\hat{\phi}$) direction.

---

To clarify, let's work with an object spinning in a circle in two dimensions, to keep things simple. A point at distance $r$ in the direction $\hat{r}$ is given by

$$\mathbf{r} = r \hat{r}.$$

where $\hat{r} = \cos\phi \hat{x} + \sin\phi \hat{y}$. The time derivative of this point is given by

$$ \mathbf{v} = \frac{dr}{dt} \hat{r} + r \frac{d\phi}{dt}\hat{\phi} $$

By **definition** $\frac{d\phi}{dt} := \omega$. Now since it is assumed that $dr/dt = 0$ we are left with

\begin{align}
\mathbf{v} &= r \omega \hat{\phi}\\
&=r\omega (-\sin\phi\hat{x} + \cos\phi \hat{y}).
\end{align}

for the full vector description.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why $\hat{r} = \cos\phi \hat{x} + \sin\phi \hat{y}$? I'm a beginner to this topic, so my knowledge isn't very adequate.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have a rigid object rotating at some angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$ about some fixed axis.  It can be shown that in general, $\vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$, where $\vec{r}$ is the instantaneous position of the object.  This more general equation *does* take the directions of the quantities into account via their cross product.

However, it is common (particularly in introductory physics texts) to consider only the case where $\vec{\omega}$ and $\vec{r}$ are at right angles to each other.  In that case, this equation simplifies to the version you have.  Recall that the magnitude of a cross product is $|\vec{A} \times \vec{B}| = |\vec{A}||\vec{B}|\sin \theta$.  This means that if $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{\omega}$ are perpendicular to each other, then we have $\theta = 90^\circ$ and
$$
v = |\vec{v}| = |\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}| = |\vec{\omega}||\vec{r}| \sin \theta = \omega r.
$$